# how to iterate nested array of objects in reactive form angular

Tags: angular, formbuilder

```json
[
   {
      "modelDetailsList":[
         {
            "modelId":499,
            "icamModelId":"1258",
            "modelName":"Polk 1  107FA",
            "modelVersionName":"CopyRETAIN59A_1_1",
            "modelVersionId":1893,
            "lockCheckList":[
               {
                  "id":667906,
                  "modelVersionId":1893,
                  "lockCheckId":139,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"No model should be locked with an EOT ending after 2050. Go to model page and configure sunset clause to 12/31/2050",
                  "lockCheckrule":"All deferred revenue should run to $0 by the end of 2050. To accomplish this, if a contract's End of Term runs past 2050 the model's Sunset Date should be set to 12/31/2050.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Override Requested",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":667907,
                  "modelVersionId":1893,
                  "lockCheckId":154,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Passed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":667917,
                  "modelVersionId":1893,
                  "lockCheckId":80,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing amounts configured in ICAM must be withinn $2500 of the actualized to date amounts in ConFIRM. Please review the data and ensure amounts match.",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing in the model do not match the Actualized to Date amounts from ConFIRM.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Failed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     {
                        "id":147,
                        "updatedDate":"11/15/2022",
                        "updatedBy":"abc",
                        "comments":"testing"
                     }
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "modelId":403,
            "icamModelId":"10663198",
            "modelName":"Thorold Cogen Project 1x7FA",
            "modelVersionName":"CopyRETAIN59A_1_1",
            "modelVersionId":3047,
            "lockCheckList":[
               {
                  "id":667985,
                  "modelVersionId":3047,
                  "lockCheckId":139,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"No model should be locked with an EOT ending after 2050. Go to model page and configure sunset clause to 12/31/2050",
                  "lockCheckrule":"All deferred revenue should run to $0 by the end of 2050. To accomplish this, if a contract's End of Term runs past 2050 the model's Sunset Date should be set to 12/31/2050.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Passed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":667986,
                  "modelVersionId":3047,
                  "lockCheckId":154,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Passed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":667996,
                  "modelVersionId":3047,
                  "lockCheckId":80,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing amounts configured in ICAM must be withinn $2500 of the actualized to date amounts in ConFIRM. Please review the data and ensure amounts match.",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing in the model do not match the Actualized to Date amounts from ConFIRM.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Failed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "modelId":419,
            "icamModelId":"440482",
            "modelName":"Red Hawk 4x7FA",
            "modelVersionName":"CopyRETAIN59A_1_1",
            "modelVersionId":3619,
            "lockCheckList":[
               {
                  "id":668064,
                  "modelVersionId":3619,
                  "lockCheckId":139,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"No model should be locked with an EOT ending after 2050. Go to model page and configure sunset clause to 12/31/2050",
                  "lockCheckrule":"All deferred revenue should run to $0 by the end of 2050. To accomplish this, if a contract's End of Term runs past 2050 the model's Sunset Date should be set to 12/31/2050.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Passed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":668065,
                  "modelVersionId":3619,
                  "lockCheckId":154,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Model region and sub region is not matching with region and sub region of configured services",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Passed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               },
               {
                  "id":668075,
                  "modelVersionId":3619,
                  "lockCheckId":80,
                  "lockCheckDescription":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing amounts configured in ICAM must be withinn $2500 of the actualized to date amounts in ConFIRM. Please review the data and ensure amounts match.",
                  "lockCheckrule":"Actualized to Date Sales, Cost, or Billing in the model do not match the Actualized to Date amounts from ConFIRM.",
                  "reason":null,
                  "ruleType":"M",
                  "statusFlag":"Failed",
                  "commentsList":[
                     
                  ],
                  "mrManagerId":null,
                  "approve":false
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "fleetId":8020,
      "fleetName":"CopyRETAIN59A_1_1"
   }
]
```

my JSON looks like this i have created form like

```js
lockChecksFleetForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    fleetGroup: this.formBuilder.array([{
        subFleetId: [],
        subFleetName: [],
        modelDetialsListGroup: this.formBuilder.array([{
            modelId: [''],
            icamModelId: [''],
            modelName: [' '],
            modelVersionName: [' '],
            modelVersionId: [' '],
            lockChecksListgroup: this.formBuilder.array([{
                id: [],
                modelVersionId: [''],
                lockCheckId: [''],
                lockCheckDescription: [''],
                lockCheckrule: [''],
                reason: [''],
                ruleType: [' '],
                statusFlag: [' '],
                commentList: ['']
            }])
        }])
    }])
})

get modelDetailsListGroupForm(): FormArray {
    return this.lockChecksFleetForm.get('modelDetialsListGroup') as FormArray
}

get lockChecksListGroupForm(): FormArray {
    return this.modelDetailsListGroupForm.get('lockChecksListgroup') as FormArray
}

initializeFleetLockCheckGrp(lockCheckDetails) {

    lockCheckDetails.forEach(group => {
        group['modelDetails'].forEach(ob => {
            const modelListGroup = this.formBuilder.group([{
                modelId: [ob.modelId],
                icamModelId: [ob.icamModelId],
                modelName: [ob.modelName],
                modelVersionName: [ob.modelVersionName],
                modelVersionId: [ob.modelVersionId],
                lockChecksListGroup: this.formBuilder.array([])
            }])
            this.modelDetailsListGroupForm.push(modelListGroup)
            ob['lockCheckList'].forEach(obj => {
                const lockcheckListGroup = this.formBuilder.group([{
                    id: [obj.id],
                    modelVersionId: [obj.modelVersion.id],
                    lockCheckId: [obj.lockCheckId],
                    lockCheckDescription: [obj.lockCheckDescription],
                    lockCheckrule: [obj.lockCheckrule],
                    reason: [obj.reason],
                    ruleType: [obj.ruleType],
                    statusFlag: [obj.statusFlag],
                    commentList: [obj.commentList]
                }])
                this.lockChecksListGroupForm.push(lockcheckListGroup)
            })
        })
        console.log('fleetGroupForm', this.lockChecksFleetForm.value)
        //this.fleetGroupForm.push(this.modelDetailsListGroupForm)
    })
}
```

getting error like modelDetailsListGroupForm is null how to set values to form and display in ui like model name along with lockchecks list

Answer (score 0):

"divide et vinces"

Create one function that return a formGroup for each "object" you has from inner to outer -the outer use the inner function-

```
newComment(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {id:0,updatedDate:"",updatedBy:"",comments:""}
   return new FormGroup({
         id:new FormControl(data.id),
         updatedDate:new FormControl(data.updateDate),
         updatedBy:new FormControl(data.updatedBy),
         comments:new FormControl(data.comments),
   })
}

newLockCheck(data:any=null)
{
  //see that by defect the "array" equal null
  data=data || {id:0,modelVersionId:0,lockCheckId:0,lockCheckDescription:"",
                lockCheckrule:"",reason:"",ruleType:"",statusFlag:"",
                mrManagerId:"",approve:false,
                commentsList:null}

  return new FormGroup({
       id:new FormControl(data.id),
       modelVersionId:new FormControl(data.modelVersionId),
       ....
       //the array we use, if is null a new FormArray, 
       //else a new FormArray transform each element of the array in a
       //formGroup: data.map(x=>this.newComment(x)

       data.commentList==null?new FormArray([]):
                              new FormArray(data.commentList
                                             .map(x=>this.newComment(x))
  })
}
newModelDetails(data:any=null)
{
   //see that by defect the "array" equal null
   data=data || {icamModelId:0,modelName:"",modelVersionName:"",...,lockCheckList:null}

    return new FormGroup({
       icamModelId:new FormControl(data.icamModelId),
       modelName:new FormControl(data.modelName),
       ...
       //see that the array it's the same structure than before
       data.lockCheckList==null?new FormArray([]):
                              new FormArray(data.lockCheckList
                                     .map(x=>this.newLockCheck(x))
    })

newFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {fleetId:0,fleetName:"",modelDetailsList:null}
   return new FormGroup({
       fleetId:new FormControl(data.fleetId),
       fleetName:new FormControl(data.fleetId),
       //This "code" sound us :)
       data.modelDetailsList==null?new FormArray([]):
                              new FormArray(data.modelDetailsList
                                  .map(x=>this.newModelDetails(x))
   })
}
```

Now we can do -see the your data is an array with one element-

```
this.form=this.newFormGroup(data[0])
```

And we write in .html only for check

```
<pre>
{{form?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

Well, **always** we has a FormArray we create a "getter". When is inside a FormArray we can not create a getter because we need the "index", but is very similar

```
get modelDetailsList()
{
   return this.form.get('modelDetailsList') as FormArray
}
//see that we need one "index"
getLockCheckList(i:number)
{
  //see that we use the "getter above"
  return this.modelDetailsList.at(i).get('lockCheckList') as FormArray
}
//see that we need two "index"
getCommentsList(i:number,j:number)
{
  //see that we use the "getter above"
  return this.getLockCheckList(i).at(j).get('commentsList') as FormArray
}
```

Puff (thanks to reach here)

Now it's the same when we have a FormArray of FomGroups

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  ...
  <div formArrayName="modelDetailsList">
      <div *ngFor="let group of modelDetailsList.controls;let i=index" 
                                            [formGroupName]="i">
          ...
          <div formArrayName="lockCheckList">
              <div *ngFor="let group2 of getLockCheckList(i).controls;let j=index"
                                            [formGroupName]="j">
                    ...
                    <div formArrayName="commentsList">
                        <div *ngFor="let group3 of getCommentsList(i,j).controls;let k=index"
                                            [formGroupName]="k">
                         ...
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

See that it's always the same

```
<div formArrayName="...">
   <div *ngFor="let ... "formArray".controls [formGroup]="index">
   </div>
</div>
```